# Canceling the start of an activity after the start was triggered by context.startActivity( newActivity )

Tags: android

I am using a 3rd-party activity (*ForeignActivity*) which as a result starts an activity (MyActivity) that I specify. To know what activity has to be started in the end, I am passing an intent to it:

```
Intent activityToStart = new Intent();
activityToStart.setClass( currentContext, MyActivity.class );
```

However, sometimes I come to a case that I do not want *MyActivity* to be started (even I passed the activityToStart intent to it). Let's say that during *ForeignActivity* execution some internal state of the app changes and the starting of *MyActivity* is not needed anymore.

*ForeignActivity* starts the *MyActivity* by:

```
currentContext.startActivity( activityToStart )
```

Is there a way, how to **cancel** starting of *MyActivity* after it was triggered? E.g. is it possible to modify/override some method inside *MyActivity* which is responsible for deciding whether activity should be started or not?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the following

Maintain a some boolean variable namely as "need_to_stop".Assign true or false based on your logic for stopping the activity

Inside the onCreate of the activity (Which you want to start /after start you want to stop)
check the boolean value then call finish() method

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
{

  //Check for the boolean value
  if(need_to_stop) finish;
  //Continue your other process

}
```